# Reload TableView data from AppDelegate.m?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I try to reload a tableView from appDelegate

in AppDelegate.m, in the method who is in charge for Push Notification, "didReceiveRemoteNotification" i call a UIAlertView everytime when a notification arrives.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification received" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", titleMsg]  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                alertView.delegate = self;
                [alertView show];
```

and when the user click "OK" button, should be a reading of database and reload the tableview

```
// Reload the table when the user click "OK" button in the alert
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if ([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Notification received"])
{
    if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        // Stop the sound for notifications
        [self stopSoundForNotifications];

        // Refresh table messages 
        AccueilViewController * avc = [[AccueilViewController alloc] init];
        [avc readMsgsFromDB];
        [avc reloadTableMsgsReceived];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReadMessagesFromDB" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadDataFromDelegate" object:nil];
    }
}
```

}

In the header i added to the protocol UIAlertViewDelegate

Do you have some ideas? Thanks

Comment: What is your problem? the Notification is not being called?

Answer (score 0):

You put the condition on cancel button instead of that put the condition on OK button 
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

```
if ([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Notification received"])
{
    if (buttonIndex == [alertView OKButtonIndex])
    {
        // then fire notification
        // Stop the sound for notifications
        [self stopSoundForNotifications];

        // Refresh table messages 
        AccueilViewController * avc = [[AccueilViewController alloc] init];
        [avc readMsgsFromDB];
        [avc reloadTableMsgsReceived];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReadMessagesFromDB" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadDataFromDelegate" object:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a new instance of `AccueilViewController`, rather than accessing an existing instance.  So those `readMsgsFromDB` and `reloadTableMsgsReceived` are being processed by an instance which is not visible.

If you amend your `AccueilViewController` code, you can register to receive those notifications, and your existing instance can then act on them to reload the data.  In fact, I would use only one notification, and combine the two method calls into one.

So delete the second postNotification, and in your `AccueilViewController` add the following to your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationReceived) name:@"ReadMessagesFromDB" sender:nil];
```

Then add a method to combine the two actions:

```
-(void)notificationReceived {
    [self readMsgsFromDB];
    [self reloadTableMsgsReceived];
}
```

So, when your `AlertView` button is pressed, the notification will be posted.  The `notificationReceived` method in your existing `AccueilViewController` instance will fire, causing the messages to be read from the database and the table to be reloaded.  You should also add a call to remove the view controller from the notification centre before it is deallocated:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ReadMessagesFromDB" object:nil];
```